# comparing 2d arrays one by one to define max values in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 2d

Could someone please help me with this issue. In advance, I really appreciate your time and consideration.
I have many same size 2d arrays. The 2d arrays are timeseries and each array is for one day, for an example;

```
day1=np.array([[4, 5, 6, 8],[9, 5, 3, 5]])
day2=np.array([[6, 0, 0, 1],[6, 1, 8, 1]])
day3=np.array([[5, 2, 7, 9],[4, 3, 7, 7]])
day4=np.array([[1, 0, 0, 7],[4, 7, 7, 3]])
```

I need to compare the arrays together and define the highest (max) values in each index and the date of the highest value. So for the above arrays (day1, day2, day3, day4), I need two outputs like below;

```
highest_values=([[6, 5, 7, 9],[9, 7, 8, 7]])
date=(['day2', 'day1', 'day3', 'day3'],['day1', 'day4', 'day2', 'day3'])
```

I could do that with the following code.

```
import numpy as np
namelist=['day1','day2','day3','day4']
arrays=np.array([day1,day2,day3,day4])
highest_values=arrays.max(axis=0) # to get the max values
index_of_max=arrays.argmax(axis=0) # to get the indices of max values
date=np.array([[namelist[j] for j in index_of_max[i]] for i in range(len(index_of_max))]) # I used the name of each array as the date and then assigned it to the indices of the max values
```

But I have thousands of large arrays saved in my computer and I need very big memory to read all the files together and run the above codes. When I run the above code for all file simultaneously, I get the out of memory error.
I need something like a loop that can read the first two arrays and take the outputs (the highest values and dating) of them, then compare the outputs with third array and take the new outputs and then compare the new outputs with the fourth array, and so on.

Comment: create a 3d array, then use `np.argmax` along the days axis. This will give day indexes, obtaining values from the indexes is trivial

Comment: Thanks @Marat. This is the way which I tried. But I have thousands of large arrays and when I run by this way, it needs very big memory to do that, which is out of my computer memory.
I need something like a code that can read the first two arrays and take the outputs (the highest values and dating) of them, then compare the outputs with third array and take the new outputs and then compare the new outputs with the forth array, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want something like

```
arrays=np.array([day1,day2,day3,day4])
highest_values = day1

for array in arrays:
    highest_values = np.array([highest_values,array]).max(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Cailean Oikawa. It works perfectly for getting the highest values. But what about dating (defining that each value belongs to which day). Thanks again!